# Add site to search engines, even though not ready yet

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engines, negative-seo

I'm building a website, and until it's done, visitors will see a *"This site will launch on new year's day 2015"*, and a description of what the site is all about

The domain is new, and nobody knows about it yet, and I want to spread the word/buzz as soon as possible

My questions is: Should I add the site to search engines now, or wait until the content is done? Will it effect later rank (or SE treatment) negatively to add it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit the site to search engines before your site is ready in order to set the domain age as older as possible (positive effect on SEO in the long term).

However, I wouldn't do it 6 months before. 1 or 2 months before the launch could be a good compromise. Think about creating the buzz about your site during this period and try to launch your site as soon as possible.

Comment: BTW- the site age comes from registration data and not the inception date.

Comment: You're right but only if the domain is indexed because of those sites which link your new domain name because they have the information from somewhere, am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right to a point, however, Google has been picking up new sites within the same day for about 2 years through registration data. It does not get all sites, however, from personal experience, it got one site I registered and deployed the same day, indexed it, and returned search traffic within about 4 hours. Amazing! The registration data sniffing was part of their anti-spam efforts and first showed up in scholar in 2008 as a part of building a trust score and authority score for sites separate from authors.

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in making the site public with a holding page including details of launch.

This is quite common and will have no negative repercussions when you do open the whole site up to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your website right away. Just make sure that pages which are not ready have a robots meta tag set to `noindex,noarchive`. When a page is ready, remove its robots meta tag.

You can already put all your pages in a *sitemap.xml* too to make sure web crawlers already know about your pages and revisit them from time to time. However, search engines won't index them while the robots meta tag is set.